# Mongodb command not recognized

Tags: mongodb, command

I am learning a mongodb tutorial and I'm new to it and I tried executing mongodb commands but the cmd is showing
C:\Users\paanc_ctx7xp6>mongod --version
'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
although I added path variable it still isn't working. I even tried adding "" after bin but anything I have done isn't working at all , and I can't seem to get an answer because everyone is simply saying to edit path variable. Can someone please help me
[path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnOS8.png)
[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of1XC.png)

Comment: This is a windows installation.  If you used a windows .msi installer file to install on windows you should have mongo available as a windows service.

Comment: Which files do you have in `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin`?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266 - The `PATH` you get with simple `echo %PATH%`

Comment: Did you try `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod" --version`?